# Is there a way to insert data from api calls into an object before its imported? Code is running before I'm able to create a variable with data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create variables and filling them with data from json api calls, but the code runs before the api calls can be made, resulting in the variables showing up empty when I try to use them. I can't figure out how to finish filling my object with data from api calls before it's being imported on a different page.

I understand that my issue is that most of the code runs before I'm able to finish setting variables that get their data from an api call, I can't figure out how to fill barChartData with variables from api calls. Any help would be insanely appreciated

//Calls json api

```
async function fetchJSONAsync(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let body = await response.json();
  return body;
}
```

//Creating movie1 variable

```
let movie1 = fetchJSONAsync('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then((apiData) => {
  movie1 = apiData.movies[0].title;
  console.log(movie1); //Logs the correct data since it waits before running
});

console.log(movie1); //Doesnt log the correct data cause code runs before movie1 is done redefining itself
```

//Bar Chart Data -> I want to insert data from the api calls into this (simple Bar Chart from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit)
console.log(movie1) results in "{ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }", I'm assuming because the api call is never finished before it's being tossed into barChartData, which gives me the Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React Child error.

```
const barChartData = {
  labels: [movie1', 'Movie Title 2', 'Movie Title 3'], //<<<Insert movie1 variable in here
  datasets: [{
    data:
    [
      200, //Irrelevant
      250, //Irrelevant
      255 //Irrelevant
    ]
  }]
}
```

Thanks again in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this :

```js
yourMethodName = async () => {
    const movie1 = await fetchJSONAsync('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
    console.log(movie1.movies[0].title);
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that before, this is the error that gives:

error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

That still wouldn't explain how I place movie1 into an object further down the page later though.

Comment: @Zango You have to put `async` keyword before method name. I have edited the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think, and i'm no expert, but if you can add an `await` to the `fetchJSONAsync` call and a `return` within the `then` clause you should be able to achieve what you need.

```
let movie1 = await fetchJSONAsync('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then((apiData) => {
  movie1 = apiData.movies[0].title;
  console.log(movie1); //Logs the correct data since it waits before running
  return movie1;
})
```

Comment: You must missunderstand, that part already works, my problem is putting the new movie1 that redefined itself into an object further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass movie1 data from state.Take another variable isFetched inital value false.
Update isFetched true once api return data.
On barChartData side,  if isFetched false then show loader else render data.